# URL of remoteEntry in Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, webpack, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, webpack-module-federation

I am trying to build a series of Micro-Frontends using Webpack 5 and the **ModuleFederationPlugin**.

In the webpack config of my container app I have to configure how the container is going to reach out to the other microfrontends so I can make use of those micro-frontends.

This all works fine when I am serving locally, not using Docker and Kubernetes and my Ingress Controller.

However because I am using Kubernetes and an Ingress Controller, I am unsure what the **remote host** would be.

[Link to Repo](https://github.com/CodeNameNinja/Micro-Service-Ticketing)

Here is my container webpack.dev.js file

```js
const { merge } = require("webpack-merge");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require("webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin");
const commonConfig = require("./webpack.common");
const packageJson = require("../package.json");

const devConfig = {
  mode: "development",
  devServer: {
    host: "0.0.0.0",
    port: 8080,
    historyApiFallback: {
      index: "index.html",
    },
    compress: true,
    disableHostCheck: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: "container",
      remotes: {
        marketing:
          "marketing@https://ingress-nginx-controller.ingress-nginx.svc.cluster.local:8081/remoteEntry.js",
      },
      shared: packageJson.dependencies,
    }),
  ],
};

module.exports = merge(commonConfig, devConfig);
```

and here is my **Ingress Config**

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: ticketing.dev
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /api/users/?(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: auth-srv
                port:
                  number: 3000
          - path: /marketing?(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: marketing-srv
                port:
                  number: 8081
          - path: /?(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: container-srv
                port:
                  number: 8080
```

and here is my marketing webpack.dev.js file

```js
const { merge } = require("webpack-merge");
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require("webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin");
const commonConfig = require("./webpack.common");
const packageJson = require("../package.json");

const devConfig = {
  mode: "development",
  devServer: {
    host: "0.0.0.0",
    port: 8081,
    historyApiFallback: {
      index: "index.html",
    },
    compress: true,
    disableHostCheck: true, // That solved it
  },
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: "marketing",
      filename: "remoteEntry.js",
      exposes: {
        "./core": "./src/bootstrap",
      },
      shared: packageJson.dependencies,
    }),
  ],
};

module.exports = merge(commonConfig, devConfig);
```

I am totally stumped as to what the remote host would be to reach out to my marketing micro-frontend

serving it as usual without running it in a docker container or kubernetes cluster, the remote host would be

`https://localhost:8081/remoteEntry.js`

but that doesn't work in a kubernetes cluster

I tried using the ingress controller and namespace, but that too, does not work

`https://ingress-nginx-controller.ingress-nginx.svc.cluster.local:8081/remoteEntry.js`

This is the error I get
[image]

Comment: Did the provided solution help you?

Answer (score 1):

> https://ingress-nginx-controller.ingress-nginx.svc.cluster.local:8081/remoteEntry.js

If your client and the node are on the same network (eg. can ping each other), do `kubectl get service ingress-nginx --namespace ingress-nginx` and take note of the nodePort# (TYPE=NodePort, PORT(S) 443:<nodePort#>/TCP). Your remote entry will be `https://<any of the worker node IP>:<nodePort#>/remoteEntry.js`

If you client is on the Internet and your worker node has public IP, your remote entry will be `https://<public IP of the worker node>:<nodePort#>/remoteEntry.js`

If you client is on the Internet and your worker node doesn't have public IP, you need to expose your ingress-nginx service with `LoadBalancer`. Do `kubectl get service ingress-nginx --namespace ingress-nginx` and take note of the `EXTERNAL IP`. Your remote entry become `https://<EXTERNAL IP>/remoteEntry.js`

Comment: so is I do the following command, I used ingress-nginx-controller instead.

`ingress-nginx-controller   LoadBalancer   10.106.187.191   localhost     80:30058/TCP,443:31645/TCP   41h`

I don't see a NodePort

Comment: You are using minikube. Try: `https://localhost:31645/remoteEntry.js`